# QImage and valgrind ; memory leak

Tags: qt, valgrind

I have an issue with the following code:

```
#include <QtGui/QImage>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QImage qimage(100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  qimage.fill(Qt::white);
  qimage.save("test.png", "PNG", 70);

  return 0;
}
```

to be compiled as followed:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/qt4 test.cpp -lQtGui
```

The code generates a proper image. However, when I valgrind it:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

it yields a series of lost blocks, like the following one:

```
==5974== 158 (56 direct, 102 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 54 of 79
==5974==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==5974==    by 0x4E4E427: QLibraryPrivate::findOrCreate(QString const&, QString const&) (qlibrary.cpp:437)
==5974==    by 0x4E4E721: QLibrary::setFileNameAndVersion(QString const&, QString const&) (qlibrary.cpp:1110)
==5974==    by 0x56290DF: ???
```

or this one :

```
==5974== 396 (56 direct, 340 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 61 of 79
==5974==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==5974==    by 0x4E4E427: QLibraryPrivate::findOrCreate(QString const&, QString const&) (qlibrary.cpp:437)
==5974==    by 0x4E44FB6: QFactoryLoader::updateDir(QString const&, QSettings&) (qfactoryloader.cpp:145)
==5974==    by 0x56F9E67: ???
```

I spare you the full log, you can just execute the same at home :)

I tried to understand and they seems to lie in the following lines I found in the source code for QImageWriter:

```
QFactoryLoader *l = loader();
QStringList keys = l->keys();
```

It seems to me that when you first try to generate a PNG image, it builds something that will be reused each time you will build a PNG image and that memory is never freed.
The destructor for QFactoryLoader seems to know how to clean things, and I would love to personally do a `delete l;`  but there is no way to call it since QFactoryLoader is private to the implementation of Qt.

One could argue that this is not a real memory leak since there would be only one key per image format, but imho, the clean way to do things would be to be able to clear everything before quitting.

So my question: is there any way to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't bother yourself this kind of problems, because Qt has systems to free all unused memory. You are looking for problems, where they don't exist. Qt will free this memory when destroying qimage object. Don't know why valgrind didn't see that.

Comment: Valgrind will find hundreds of possible memory leaks in the Qt implementation if you run it on any larger Qt-based project. I don't know if all these are true memory leaks or if valgrind just gets confused by the massive use of pointers inside Qt. However, as already stated, I wouldn't bother about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt's image I/O functionality is based around plugins.  When you request a `QImage` to a load a png file the PNG library is loaded as a `QObject` *once*, it is not unloaded until the program exits - this is what Valgrind sees as a memory leak.

Comment: That's how I felt it was going. This reminds me some kind of Singleton design pattern (for the list of loaded plugins) but they do not cause any problem for valgrind do they?

Comment: So isn't there any way to manually clean the list of loaded plugins?

Comment: No, but why would you want to?  They are designed to last the lifetime of the application, and are cleaned up by the OS.

Comment: My purpose is to make valgrind be quiet and not be bothered by Qt noise when I inspect the rest of my program. I am just convinced that a program should not rely on the OS to clean his s***.

Comment: I'm in agreement there but only for neatness' sake, it is not a memory leak as no more memory is consumed than is needed for the plugin to run; and your OS cleans up your stack, is it so far fetched for it to clean up your heap allocation as well?  As for Valgrind, to silence various kinds of output use a Suppression file (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress).

Answer (score -2):

Why aren't you using the QCoreApplication. Only then the QObject GC will be in action. Only then proper clean up will work. Qt is internally built around too many pointers which are managed by the main event loop with out which it is totally messy and destructive.

Comment: `QObject` child destruction has nothing to do with `QCoreApplication`.